# Is that possible to generate unique Id for list item across site collection?

Tags: numbers, field

Ex: I have 10 sites and every site have 5 list. From site 1 i have adding one item in listX now id will be like "1" and creating another item in listB of 4th sub site so now id will "2"... So it has to go on like this how to achieve this?

I need to update this with all list item added event ? also how to get the latest id?

Answer (score 0):

I have tried this code with custom forms it's work's cool, but thinking this may give concurrency issue

```
    public static void ID()
    {
        if ((field.InternalName.Equals("Field1")))
                                {
                                     {
          string template;
          using (SPSite site = new SPSite(SPContext.Current.Site.Url))
          {
              using (SPWeb web = site.RootWeb)
              {
template = web.Properties["eydtemplate"].ToString();
              }
          }
          if ("eydadvisory" == template)
          {
              SPListItemCollection items = _currentList.Items;
              if (_currentList.ItemCount == 0)
              {
webControl.Field.DefaultValue = (1).ToString();
              }
              else
              {
SPQuery query = new SPQuery();
query.RowLimit = 1;
query.Query = " <OrderBy><FieldRef Name='" + field.InternalName + "' Ascending='FALSE' /></OrderBy>";
webControl.Field.DefaultValue = (Convert.ToInt64(_currentList.GetItems(query).Cast<SPListItem>().FirstOrDefault()[field.InternalName]) + 1).ToString();
              }
          }
      }
```